# Handling Image Uploads in Django

Tags: django, file-upload

I have this view for my form:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    vehicle = VehicleForm(request.POST or None)
    photos = PhotosFormSet(request.POST or None)
    if vehicle.is_valid() and photos.is_valid():
        new = vehicle.save()
        photos = PhotosFormSet(request.POST, instance=new)
        photos.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/vehicles/')
else:
    prefix = "09-"
    queryset = Vehicle.objects.all().order_by("stock_number")
    if queryset == None:
        last_rec = queryset.reverse()[0]
        a = str(last_rec.stock_number)
        b = int(a[-3:])+1
        next = prefix+str(b)
    else:
        next = prefix+"001"
    vehicle = VehicleForm(initial={'stock_number': next})
    photos = PhotosFormSet(instance=Vehicle())
```

However when I try to save the record, the image field in `PhotosFormset` gives an error saying `This field is required.`

`PhotosFormset` is declared as `PhotosFormSet = generic_inlineformset_factory(Photo, extra=5)`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't appear to be binding uploaded files to your formset. You need to pass in request.FILES as well as request.POST:

```
photos = PhotosFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=new)
```

More info in the [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files)

Comment: I was just going over than bit of the docs a few minutes back and saw the same bit.  Thanks

Comment: I also needed enctype="multipart/form-data" in my <form> element in addition to request.FILES